# Wait for button press

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, button, c++-cli

Is it possible to make a function wait until a specific button is pressed?
For example I have a function called `foo()` and i want it to act like this:

```
void foo(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a*b;
    if(some_button got pressed)
        MessageBox::Show(result.ToString());
}
```

Note that i don't want code like this inside the button:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    foo1(num1,num2);
}
void f1(int a, int b)
{
    int result = a*b;
    MessageBox::Show(result.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What do you imagine the program will do while waiting? Windows will label such a program as "Not Responding" and users will go to Task Manager and kill it.

Comment: `Note that i don't want code like this inside the button` Why don't you? No, really, why? What's the real goal of the exercise?

Comment: The goal is eventually i'll have an option that determines whether the program runs automatically or by pressing a `"Next"` button to see the next step. So if the user chooses manual running, the program needs to stop after every step and wait for pressing `Next`.

Comment: That's not how event-driven programs work. You need a variable indicating which stage of processing you are at. So you would call the function that completes the first stage, set that variable accordingly, and return to the message pump. When Next button is pressed, you would consult the variable, determine that you need to perform the second stage, call the corresponding function, update the variable, and return to the message pump. And so on, for each stage.

Comment: Yeah i figured that way... But thought there's something eaiser